# Which is better approach for getting sorted data

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, treemap

I need to write sorted data to file. The data (IP objects) is sorted on basis of IP (String, a property of an IP object).

So I have two options either take a TreeMap and insert data into treeMap or after getting all the data then sorting it.

i.e.

```
Map<String, IPObject>> map = new TreeMap<>(new IPComparator);
```

or

Store simply all objects in ArrayList and then call sort method as

```
Collection.sort(ip_Object_List, new IPListComparator);
```

so which approach is better and efficient ?

Comment: You're basically asking whether an insertion sort is better or more efficient than the sort algorithm used by `Collections.sort`. My sense is "yes, probably" but really, your best bet is to test it with your actual data — being aware of A) The dangers of microbenchmarking the JVM, and B) The dangers of premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the "which approach is better" depends a great deal on the purpose for which you need an approach.

1. If your `ip_Object_List` is created once, and never changed after that, then `Collection.sort` approach is more efficient, because liter iteration runs faster
2. If your `map` is updated frequently, and you always want to access it in sorted order, `TreeMap<>` representation may be faster, depending on how often you iterate it.

It is somewhat unlikely that the approach you take would make visible difference in terms of performance and efficiency, so pick whichever one is more comfortable for you. One should consider an alternative representation only if a profiler run tells that the code is spending too much CPU or memory in the structure that you picked.

Answer (score 1):

These are both O(n log n) operations. With Collections.sort() there is no additional space needed, whereas the TreeMap will have O(n) space used to maintain the map. If you are going to frequently add, then sort the list then the TreeMap is better - each new insert is only O(log n). Keeping the data structure allows you to quickly search for elements and do all sorts of other operations on the data set.

So, if you are going to access and modify the sorted set, use the TreeMap else just sort it.